# Formula (layout ribbon) number format to display negative symbol to left of currency indicator

Tags: microsoft-word

**Background:**  I am using a table in word and am summing the currency values, USD, using a `Formula`, listed under the `Layout` ribbon in Word.

---

**Problem:**  When these sum, if the value is negative, the `-` is displaying to the right of the `$`.

---

**Inquiry:**

Does anyone know how to get the `-` to display to the left of the `$` when summing using the `Formula` under the `Layout` ribbon?

---

**Related image:**

The summed value with the formula and numberformat displays as `$-110,313` (the highlighted section in the table with grey fill), while the desired location (with the manually removed and added elsewhere `-`) would display as `-$100,313`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this for the Number Format works:

```
$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00
```

**Explanation:**

The part before the semicolon tells Word how to format positive numbers. The part after the semicolon tells Word how to format negative numbers. If you leave out the explicit negative format, it, as you've found, defaults to `$-#,##0.00`, putting the negative sign on the right side of the currency symbol. To get it to put the negative sign on the left, specify `-$#,##0.00` for the negative portion of the format.

Or, in field notation, use this for the field:

```
=SUM(ABOVE) \# "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00"
```

(Tested in Word 2013.)

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation!  Makes a bit more sense some of the items for accounting format.